# Add Android Support Library Repository to Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, android-support-library

I have a Nexus server running on a remote server and I'd like to link the local repository for the android support libraries to Nexus. How can I do this?

Comment: why don't you just push these libraries to nexus?

Comment: @EngineerDollery I want to avoid that because it's an extra step after updating in the Android Support Repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use the [Maven Android SDK Deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) to push all artifacts from the SDK including the support library and other artifacts from the Maven repo within the SDK to Nexus.

In Maven the local "repository" is not really that. It is simply a cache. Never treat it as a permanent storage for anything. It should be fine to be deleted any time and should be just repopulated from the repo manager.

Comment: I figured as much. I wish Google would just put this stuff on central and stop being difficult. I was trying to get rid of this extra step. Maybe it's time to write a script that kicks off the deployer after an update.

Answer (score 0):

On your server where Nexus is running, copy the android-sdk folder there.  Make sure you keep it up to date.

In this folder, you will find: `android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository`

This is where the Maven artefacts are found for your Android SDK installation.

Now, on Nexus, add a new "Hosted" repository, and under the configuration tab for that hosted repository, enter the "Override Local Storage" location. Something like:

`file:/c:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository`

You should also set the Deployment Policy for this Hosted repository to Read Only.

You can also add this new hosted repository to your Public Repositories group in Nexus, and therefore access the Android dependencies via http://yournexusserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/